# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tapas.utils'

Tags: machine-learning, data-science, artificial-intelligence

I am getting the above error while trying to import these method. I am using Collab.

from tapas.utils import tf_example_utils

from tapas.protos import interaction_pb2

from tapas.utils import number_annotation_utils

from tapas.scripts import prediction_utils

**I tried to install utils but it didn't work**

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: While importing module named tf_example_utils from the tapas.utils package. I am getting error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tapas.utils' ". Any solution